# jcarousel circular carousel issue

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel plugin for a slideshow. It is a circular carousel which initially contains 3 images. Please find the code section below. I am posting only the HTML structure and not the actual HTML which contains the image path and classes.

***HTML***

```
<ul id="adcarousel">
    <li>
        <img src="imagepath1" alt="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="imagepath2" alt="2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="imagepath3" alt="3" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
jQuery('#adcarousel').jcarousel({
    auto: 1,
    wrap: 'circular',
    scroll: 1,
    animation: "fast",
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,
});
```

What happens is that after each transition the number of li elements get increased. Is there any way by which this can be solved?

Thanks in advance